# Dynamic HTML lang property in statically generated Next.js pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a multilange static landing page in a Next.Js project.
My goal is to have the following structure:

- / -> English Home page
- /de -> German Home page
- /it -> Italian Home page

I'm building it in the following way:

pages/index.js

```
export default function Home() {
  return <div>English Homepage</div>
}
```

pages/de.js

```
export default function Home() {
  return <div>German page</div>
}
```

In order to make the website accessible, I would like to set html lang accordingly.

pages/_document.js

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang={???}>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I specify the language per page?
I tried with `getInitialProps`, but that forces my website to be SSR.

Comment: Did you find how to do it? I'm trying to accomplish exactly the same thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You are indeed right about using `getInitialProps`.** Unlike `getInitialProps` in normal pages that will disable Automatic Static Optimization, `getInitialProps` in `_document.js` has no such effect.

It is because `Document` is only rendered in the server. `Document`'s `getInitialProps` function is not called during client-side transitions, nor when a page is statically optimized. [More about its technical details](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#caveats)

That's why you can use it to inject a `lang` prop into pages and still get the benefits of static optimization.

```
// _document.js
...
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
  const { pathname } = ctx;
  const lang = pathname.startsWith("/de") ? "de" : "en";
  return { ...initialProps, lang };
}
...
```

To have the `lang` attribute also updated during client-transitions, you have to also set up an `useRouter` hook in `_app.js` to watch the route change:

```
// _app.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const { pathname } = useRouter();
  const lang = pathname.startsWith("/de") ? "de" : "en";
  useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.lang = lang;
  }, [lang]);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

I have created this CodeSandbox for you as a demo.

[image: Edit dynamic-html-lang-property-in-statically-generated-next-js-pages]

Download it to your local machine and inspect the code. After `npm install`, run `npm run build`. You will see from the Build Logs that both "/" and "de" are static. Run `npm start` and view the page source, you will see the `lang` attribute is set properly in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks Hangindev,
your proposal works. The only problem is that if you change the language on the page without a reload of the page the html language attribute will not be changed. My workaround for that problem is simply refreshing the page on language change.

Comment: I see your point. I have updated the answer as well as the CodeSandbox to update the `lang` attribute during client-transitions using `useRouter` hook in `_app.js`.

Comment: This works for if you use Next's own i18n. I this case Next handles everything for you and you don't need to do anything in `_document.js`. The hard and useful bit is if you cannot use Next's i18n - how do you then set then _dynaimcally_ set the `lang` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Hey maybe not the best solution, but should work, you can use `dangerousAsPath` prop on `_document.jsx` page and decide the `lang` based on the path.

```
render() {
  return (
   <Html lang={this.props.dangerousAsPath === '/de' ? 'de' : 'en'}>
     {/* ... */}
   </Html>
  )
}
```

Again there probably should be a better solution for this. Cheers.

Edit:
There might be a chance that `dangerousAsPath` will be [removed](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/10773/commits/548f9091c64c96412093338435fce612a34c2450), if so you can use `this.props.__NEXT_DATA__.page` until you find a better option.

Comment: This relies that your locale is in your URL path

Answer (score 0):

For your example, if you assume your urls will always follow this pattern 
`https://somedomain.com/{lang}/everything-else`,

then you could extract the `lang` from the url like:

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)

    // `ctx.req.path` would be of pattern: `/{lang}/everything-else`
    // ctx.req.path.split('/') --> ['', 'lang', 'everything-else']
    const locale = ctx.req.path.split('/')[1]

    return { ...initialProps, locale }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // get the language 
      <Html lang={this.props.locale}>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

As a side-note, I'd suggest exploring [next-i18next](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next) package, for a more standard way of implementing localization in next.js

Comment: What if your URLs don't follow that pattern?