# How to set HTML lang attribute for a specific page in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a Next.js website with multiple pages.

All pages are in English except one which is in French which doesn't have an English version of it.

How can I set the HTML tag `lang` attribute on that specific page?

This is not something I could achieve using [next/head](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) or with a [custom document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document).

My `_document.js` class currently looks like this, so that English is the default for all pages:

```js
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

What I would need is to dynamically set the `lang` attribute value to `fr` for one specific page.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Dynamic HTML lang property in statically generated Next.js pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62297280/dynamic-html-lang-property-in-statically-generated-next-js-pages)?

Answer (score 0):

I think for this, one the easiest solution could be layouts.

You can read more about here

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts

And add Next custom Tags

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

Comment: Hello, this doesn't work, as a custom Layout can't manage the `html` tag as far as I know.

Comment: @MichaëlPerrin Yes their documentation doesn't work at all.